# Keycloak: roles not assigned when user is created via CLI

Tags: keycloak, redhat-sso

Running the below commands to import user with roles.

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password [pass]

./kcadm.sh create users -r [realm_name] -f user-admin.json
```

*user-admin.json* looks like:

```
{
  "username": "adminLocal",
  "enabled": true,
  "totp": false,
  "emailVerified": false,
  "firstName": "admin",
  "lastName": "local",
  "email": "adminLocal@domain.com",
  "disableableCredentialTypes": ["password"],
  "requiredActions": [],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "access": {
    "manageGroupMembership": true,
    "view": true,
    "mapRoles": true,
    "impersonate": true,
    "manage": true
  },
  "credentials" : [ 
                    {
                        "value" : "secret", 
                        "type"  : "password",
                        "temporary" : false 
                    } 
                   ],
  "realmRoles" : ["admin","offline_access","uma_authorization"]
}
```

Expected all the specified roles in **"realmRoles"** key to be assigned. However just `Realm Default Roles: "offline_access","uma_authorization"` were assigned to user.
The roles exist and were added beforehand via Keycloak Admin UI.

It's possible to create user and then assign roles as a workaround. However would like to do it with one command.

Comment: It is a bug in keycloak REST API, https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9354.